# Why is $DEFAULT_SITE_URL appearing in entries URL?

Tags: craft3, entries, url

I have an entry loop on my homepage that uses `{{ entry.url }}` that links to the full entry. When I click on the entry, the url looks like this

**mydomain.com/$DEFAULT_SITE_URL/the-entrys-slug**

Even though my section settings just has the Entry URI Format set to `{slug}`

Here's my entry loop if you need it

```
{% set aBetterPost = craft.entries.section('aBetterPost').limit('6').all() %}
{% for entry in aBetterPost %}
    <div class="main-post">
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
            Entry Stuff...
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**How can I get rid of the $DEFAULT_SITE_URL ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have a misconfiguration in your environment variables - First go to the control panel and check what you have under Settings > Sites > [choose site] > Base URL. If it's set to an env variable (i.e. it begins with a dollar sign), go to wherever you store your environment variables (e.g. the `.env` file, or maybe server env vars if you're on the remote), and check that you have a variable there with the expected value.